# Find the latest plants by category doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How to get the latest plants by category, ManyToMany relationship, using doctrine can help me I'm struggling a lot

Entity Plant
[image]

Entity plant_category
[image]

Entity category
[image]

```
$sql = "SELECT category_id, c.name, c.slug, i.name
FROM category AS c
LEFT JOIN plant_category AS pc
ON pc.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM plant
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS i
ON pc.plant_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.id, i.name
ORDER BY c.id ASC";
```

I did a search but I couldn't find anything yet with doctrine

```
$t = $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
->select("c")
->from(Plant::class, "p")
->leftJoin('p.categories', 'cc')
->leftJoin('(SELECT id, name FROM plant
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
ON pc.plant_id = i.id', "i");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine ORM works a bit differently than working with a standard SQL query.

To work with the entities, the separation of concerns changes from an abstraction (non-deterministic array) to a static model (deterministic object).
In that your `Category` entity is expected to have an association for the `i.name` column of your query for the desired end-result, otherwise a [partial object](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/partial-objects.html) is implicated, which is highly discouraged due it causing an invalid state of the entity.

You're attempting to solve for a special circumstance where you want to show a single specific record from the `ManyToMany` association of the `Category::$plants` collection, which goes against the Object Model design pattern. The object models are expected to be **Valid at all times**, so accounting for those special circumstances from the context of the ORM breaks that core principal.

In short, the ORM should not be doing that, you're most likely looking for an array result (as given in the answer by [@JeanCapelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4226049/jeancapelle)) or a native query.

### Criteria on the Object Model

The simplest workaround is to utilize the object model with a [criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) applied to the collection to filter the results and obtain the desired results. However, the use of criteria on the model is also highly discouraged as it heavily impacts performance and has implications of an invalid entity state.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class Category
{
    /**
     * @return Collection|Plants[]
     */
    private $plants;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ...
        $this->plants = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getPlants(): Collection
    {
        return $this->plants;
    }


    public function getLatestPlant(): ?Plant
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()->setMaxResults(1);

        return $this->plants->matching($criteria->orderBy(['id', 'DESC']))->first() ? : null;
    }
}
```

Then the query would be changed to the following.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$t = $qb->select('c')
    ->from(Category::class, 'c')
    ->addSelect('p')
    ->leftJoin('c.plants', 'p')
    ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');

$categories = $t->getQuery()->getResult();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $latestPlant = $category->getLatestPlant();
    echo $latestPlant->getName();
}
```

### Object Model Association on Latest

The more favorable solution considered [best-practice](http://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/), would be to add the foreign key association to the `Category` table and a `ManyToOne` relationship on the `Category` Entity, instead of relying on a subquery to filter from the association. Where the latest plant is maintained through the application and the object model lifecycle.

Category table: `id, name, description, slug, latest_plant`

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @return Collection|Plants[]
     */
    private $plants;

    /**
     * @return null|Plant
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Plant::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="latest_plant", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private ?Plant $latestPlant = null;

    public function getPlants(): Collection
    {
        return $this->plants;
    }

    // simple example on how to maintain relationship
    public function addPlant(Plant $plant)
    {
        if (!$this->plants->contains($plant)) {
            $this->plants->add($plant);
            $plant->addCategory($this);
            $this->setLatestPlant($this->plants->last() ?: null);
        }
    }

    // simple example on how to maintain relationship
    public function removePlant(Plant $plant)
    {
        if ($this->plants->contains($plant)) {
            $this->plants->removeElement($plant);
            $plant->removeCategory($this);
            if ($this->latestPlant && $this->latestPlant->getId() === $plant->getId()) {
                $this->setLatestPlant($this->plants->last() ?: null);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getLatestPlant(): ?Plant
    {
        return $this->latestPlant;
    }

    public function setLatestPlant(?Plant $plant)
    {
        $this->latestPlant = $plant;
    }
}
```

Then the query would look like the below.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$t = $qb->select('c')
    ->from(Category::class, 'c')
    ->addSelect('lp')
    ->leftJoin('c.latestPlant', 'lp') // Category::$latestPlant
    ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');

$categories = $t->getQuery()->getResult();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $latestPlant = $category->getLatestPlant();
    echo $latestPlant->getName();
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your explanation it is great and a very good practice.
I chose the second solution
which suits my expectations perfectly.
You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL querie is what you expect, I'll suggest you to try something like :

```
$qb->select('c.id AS category_id', 'c.name', 'c.slug', 'i.name')
   ->from('Category', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('c.plantCategories', 'pc')
   ->innerJoin(
       '(SELECT p.id, p.name FROM Plant p ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 1)', 
       'i', 
       Join::WITH, 
       'pc.plant = i.id'
   )
   ->groupBy('c.id', 'c.name', 'c.slug', 'i.name')
   ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');

$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Hello thank you
for your great request, now I better understand how doctrine works.
Perfect